# DevEx XtraGrid display as chart

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a DevEx Xtragrid component displaying multiple sets of numeric data. I would like to show this as multiple series on a line chart. I want to toggle between displaying the data in a grid and on a chart at the click of a button.

Is there an 'easy' way in DevEx to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the specific UserControls/Views based on grid and chart and then dock both into the single container(Panel). To toggle display mode you can use the following code:

```
viewGrid.Dock = Dock.Fill;
viewGrid.Visible = true; // show grid initially
viewGrid.Parent = pnlContainer;
viewChart.Dock = Dock.Fill;
viewChart.Visible = false; // hide chart initially
viewChart.Parent = pnlContainer;
// ...
void btn_ToggleView(object sender, EventArgs e){
    bool showChart = viewGrid.Visible;
    viewGrid.Visible = !showChart;
    viewChart.Visible = showChart;
}
```

P.S. DevExpress also provides the [Navigation Frame](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114554/Controls-and-Libraries/Navigation-Controls/Navigation-Frame-and-Tab-Pane) container that hosts multiple pages and allows only one of them to be displayed at a time.

Comment: Thanks, the approach described would have been where I was heading. I thought I'd ask if there were some properties, methods in devex though that allow chart and grid to be linked etc. Devex is so feature rich and has sooo many properties it is easy to be unaware of some features.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, Dx has a lot of features, so when talking about the integration Chart with Data Grid, I suggest you review the [Integration with a Data Grid, Vertical Grid, Tree List or List Box via ControlRowSource](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/119224/controls-and-libraries/chart-control/data-processing/data-providing/integration-with-a-data-grid-vertical-grid-tree-list-or-list-box-via-controlrowsource) article)).